# Was this edit acceptable?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, etiquette, rollbacks, specific-edit

#### Note: links only available to 10K+ users.

I made an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/45310859/2) on [Define a function and assign it to a method in a ECMAScript 6 Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45310859/define-a-function-and-assign-it-to-a-method-in-a-ecmascript-6-class) which was immediately rolled back.

The edit attempted to put the code in the question together into a stack snippet to show the asker *with easily accessible evidence* that the error they claimed was not reproducible, and *gave them a template which would be easy to edit* and introduce the error with more detail from whatever code they had originally.

In addition, my edit applied a <s>strikethrough</s> to a clause in a sentence that said something to the effect of:

> something something..., <s>but obviously the code doesn't work.</s>

just before the stack snippet I placed into the question, which was literally comprised of code copied-and-pasted verbatim from each of the code blocks originally in the question.

The rest of the question remained untouched.

I immediately followed this edit up with a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45310859/define-a-function-and-assign-it-to-a-method-in-a-ecmascript-6-class#comment77584075_45310859) informing the asker to edit their question and create a verifiable example, and a close-vote as off-topic since the error was "no longer reproducible."

What policy, if any, was I violating, by making that edit? I did not change the intent of the code, and I did not "solve the problem" in the question, it was already invalid to begin with.

For reference, there was a comment posted by the user who rolled back, to explain the reason just before the question was deleted by the OP which read:

> Edits should improve questions/answers. Your edit changed the posts meaning without substantially improving it. Edits are also not a way to communicate with the OP. Furthermore, your edit obscures the question for passers-by.

In my defense, I don't think that my edit changed the post's meaning, I think it improved it by giving a verifiable example, and I don't think that my edit attempted to directly communicate with the OP. I *can* however, understand the claim that my edit may have obscured the question, but anyone with much experience in JavaScript would have quickly realized the fallacy even without the edit, in my opinion.

My goal with this meta discussion is to get a better understanding of what's considered within the realm of "acceptable" edits.

Comment: Who rolled back the edit? The author? Another user? A mod?

Comment: @Kendra another user, with a similar amount of reputation to me.

Comment: Once I get another 100 rep, I'll be able to cite things like the edit summary and directly quote my comment (yay!)

Comment: Sorry but your edit basically reads: `I have a problem -- No I don't have a problem`.

Comment: The more I look at it the more I think your edit was not appropriate.  IMHO it should have been a comment with a link to something like jsfiddle showing the code working and asking them for a  mcve that does not.

Comment: @ayhan well, not literally, but I did strikethrough one clause in a sentence that said (iirc) "but obviously it didn't work"

Comment: @NathanOliver I had considered that, but given the apparent inexperience of the asker, I thought it'd be better to provide an example where the logged output was accessible without using developer tools, and I thought it also served as a template that they could edit the actual suspect code into. I can understand where you're coming from though.

Comment: And to add to the discussion, this is what idmean wrote just before the OP deleted the question "@PatrickRoberts Edits should improve questions/answers. Your edit changed the posts meaning without substantially improving it. Edits are also not a way to communicate with the OP. Furthermore, your edit obscures the question for passers-by. – idmean"

Comment: @ayhan ah, thank you. I wasn't able to read that before the post got deleted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just copy-pasting the entirety of the OP's code and including it in the question a second time is just noise.  The question isn't better off duplicating the code.

Your strike through of the OP's statement of the problem is just wrong.  If you can't reproduce the OP's problem then by all means post a comment saying as much, and vote to close the question accordingly (both of which you did), but to edit the question to change the statement of the problem just because you can't reproduce it is wrong, and was correctly rolled back.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Is there any case where a question that should be closed would benefit from having the code moved into a stack snippet if it is runnable?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I mean if you take a code in a regular code snippet and make it a stack snippet, without actually adding or removing any code, that's at least *potentially* valid.  In this case the entire question is structured in such a way that that change isn't really feasible, as the explanation is intermigned with snippets of the code.  I don't typically spend a lot of time answering questions in fields that use stack snippets, so I couldn't comment much on the specifics of when it is and isn't appropriate to turn a regular code snippet to a stack snippet.

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts If the question would still need to be closed *after* the edit, I wouldn't bother.